# Make lstlisting more colorful

Tags: listings, color, verbatim, syntax-highlighting

I find the result of lstlisting is not very impressive.
Take C++ for example, it fails to distinguish keywords and typename, or variable names and namespace.
Open any well-established code editor, like Sublime text or Vim, and you see.

I found `lstset`, but I believe there are still room of improvement.

```
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{black},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{teal},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray},
    identifierstyle=\color{red},
    stringstyle=\color{blue}
}
```

Example screenshot:

[image: code_listing]

Any suggestion to make lstlisting more colorful?

Comment: Please specify what exactly you want to change (expect, i.e. by adding another screenshot). Furthermore you should have a look at the flexible `minted`.

Comment: You should consider as well that most times code listings are ignored ;-)

Comment: partially: "it fails to distinguish keywords and typename, or variable names and namespace"; if you want exact answer... I don't know how exactly is the way Vim syntax highlighting is implemented, so I cannot clearly articulate what it is lacking. But the difference is sure enough.